# Use express to link urls to window locations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to write something that automatically...

`example.com/woot` -> `example.com/#woot`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var parsed = url.parse(incomingUrl);
parsed.pathname.replace(/\//, "/#");
var outgoingUrl = url.format(parsed);
```

Why you want to do this is another question

Comment: hrrm, I have a one page application with a few different parts. Too small for routes with backbone or something. I was just going to call state changes based on window location. Bad idea? The goal was that people could still just link to `example.com/thing` and have it trigger the function for `thing()` on load.

Comment: @fancy I would use davis for that.